# Jquery Selector select div with class having some title

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a div with class charts 
having title which contain (0%)

for example i have 5 div

```
<div class="charts" title ="book1 (0%)" ></div>

<div class="charts" title ="book2 (10%)" ></div>

<div class="charts" title ="book3 (20%)" ></div>

<div class="charts" title ="book4 (0%)" ></div>

<div class="charts" title ="book5 (0%)" ></div>
```

I am doing it with jquery but no luck

Please Help

Comment: provide your html and what you tried so far

Comment: Any code, any good explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div.charts[title*="(0%)"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

```
$('.charts[title*="(0%)"]').hide();
```